# Using a datamember type of list

Tags: wcf, list, observablecollection, datamember

i'm new with wcf and i create a DataContract like this :

```
    [DataContract]
    public class directoriesUser
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string NameDir { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public directoriesUser Parent { get; set; }


        private ObservableCollection<directoriesUser> _userDirs = new ObservableCollection<directoriesUser>();

        [DataMember]
        public ObservableCollection<directoriesUser> UserDirectories
        {
            get { return _userDirs; }
            set { _userDirs = value; }
        }
    }
```

But whe i use this class like above, the service throw an exception. can someone help me ?

```
    public directoriesUser getHomeUser(int user_id)
    {
        directoriesUser dirhome = new directoriesUser();
        // this doesn't works
        dirhome.UserDirectories = new ObservableCollection<directoriesUser>{
            new directoriesUser { NameDir = "dir1", Parent = dirhome},
            new directoriesUser {NameDir = "dir2", Parent = dirhome}
        };
        // neither this one
        dirhome.UserDirectories.Add(new directoriesUser {NameDir = "dir3", Parent = dirhome})
        return dirhome;
    }
```

Comment: i get this "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directoriesUser class probably causes recursion when wcf serializes the instance. This is basically caused by the Parent property pointing back up the hierarchy.
Here's a [more detailed article](http://blog.andrewrivers.co.uk/2009/05/problems-with-recursion-in-wcf.html) about this.